# What button labels would best describe the experience of talking to a virtual assistant?

Tags: usability

**Background:**
I have a virtual assistant which sits on a website with the purpose of helping people with their general 'FAQ' type questions. So, when you launch the chat feature, there are two buttons to choose from, those are 'Talk to Rachel' and 'Text only chat'. The 'Talk to Rachel' is a 3D avatar video experience that is full screen, Rachel welcomes you, her facial gestures are modeled on human behaviour, shes looks very real.

**The problem:**
Research has told me that the button label to the 3D avatar isn't telling  customers enough about what to expect. The label 'Talk to Rachel' is confusing people who more-than-often think its a text chat or voice interaction, they are uncomfortably surprised when they were prompted to try the experience. I know most people would go for the text only chat as they are more confident with this option.

**Question:**
Since 'Talk to Rachel' is confusing people, and giving them enough of an idea of what to expect, what label do you think it should be?

Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about 'Video chat with Rachel'?
That would clearly indicate that there will be a video involved and it's not only a text chat - so the difference to the other option is clear as well.

Comment: Thanks to all replies. I wouldn't rely on icons alone to give an idea of intent so I like this idea with video in the button label 'along with icon'. For me, this offers more people understanding via tools they use to read the screen and those that respond better to visual cues like the video icon.

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in one-line of text for each option then I would say:

- Message Rachel
- Meet with Rachel

However, adding some icons and some sub-text can work wonders for clarity.

(please excuse the colours and icons, they are just a quick example)

[image]

---

I think one of the key off-puts of seeing a video of someone is that the user might instinctively assume: "If I can see them, does that mean they can see me". For a lot of users this is going to make them feel uncomfortable and no matter how you label the buttons, the shock of seeing a full screen avatar is always going to be there.

To help negate this concern, one option would be that upon clicking "Meet with Rachel" (or whatever text you go with), that the user is prompted with a warning message, something along the lines of:

> *Meeting Rachel is an interactive video experience where you will be able to see a video avatar of Rachel.*

> *Rachel has been designed to look realistic and respond as you might expect a real person to respond. However, she is computer generated and not a real person.*

> *Don't worry, although you can see Rachel, she cannot see you.*

Then you can provide the user with "Continue" and "Cancel" options.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for :

- "Ask Rachel" (interactive 3D)
- "Ask Rachel" (text only)

This way, you are suggesting that the level of assistance is the same (which is the core of the users need at that point), but the experience is different, all while clearly stating where the difference lies.

I also second @musefan on the warning message :

> To help negate this concern, one option would be that upon clicking "Meet with Rachel" (or whatever text you go with), that the user is prompted with a warning message